# Docker - Update ENV variable in specific file

Tags: docker

I have this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
USER root
WORKDIR /root/

ENV PORT 3000

COPY ./start.sh /root/
COPY ./pubsubserver /root/

RUN mkdir -p public
ADD public /root/public

CMD ["/root/start.sh"]
```

and `start.sh`:

```
sed -i 's/"port":""/"port":"$PORT"' public/port.json

./pubsubserver --port $PORT
```

and `port.json`(before build image and run container):

```
{
"port":""
}
```

Basically, when I build the image, `pubsubserver`, `start.sh` will be copied to `root` folder at `Docker`, and the whole `public/` folder will be transferred into `root` folder at `Docker` too.

But when I run container:

```
docker run --name demo -e "PORT=5000"
```

I can get my `pubsubserver` getting the port 5000, but my `port.json` will get:

```
"port":"$PORT"
```

which I expect:

```
"port":"5000"
```

How can I resolve this?

I read about `ENTRYPOINT` that might be about to solve this, but I am not sure how to get it to work.

Comment: Just tried your idea, not working. the result is `"port":""`, means it did not change at all.

Comment: you're completely right. I reproduced the issue and think I found the solution, seems to be with your `sed` line. I was able to get the desired output with `sed -i "s/\"port\":\"\"/\"port\":\"$PORT\"/" public/port.json`. But @xdhmoore's solution also works and has less annoying double quote escaping.

Comment: Also, for debugging adding `set -x` to your `start.sh` would be helpful for debugging. Running it as is resulted in an error with the sed line: `sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: Do you actually need to make the port number inside the container configurable?  Each container runs in an isolated network namespace, so different container processes can listen on the same port; the `docker run -p` option can map the ports to different non-conflicting host ports if needed.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, I need that. in the container is a go module that in charge of 2 things, a websocket and HTTP server. this port.json is for the http side to know which port the container is running at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your sed line. If your outermost quotes are single quotes, it won't do parameter expansion. I think what you want is something like:

```
sed -i 's/"port":""/"port":'$PORT'/' public/port.json
```

However, instead of replacing exactly the string `"port":""`, why not make it a little more flexible and templatey and replace just a homemade `{{PORT}}` token:

port.json:

```
{
"port":"{{PORT}}"
}
```

sed line:

```
sed -i "s/{{PORT}}/$PORT/" public/port.json
```

That way if your json formatting changes it won't break.